# how to stop page from refreshing when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html

everytime i submit a form from my site it refreshes back up to the top
ive done `const sendEmail = (e) => { e.preventDefault()` so I dont know where I go wrong with it.

It also submits something everytime I reload the page even though theres no input.

ive tried digging up everything I can find, but to no avail I dont really know whats wrong i've only been coding for a year im only a 16yr old senior highschool so please help me.

this is the html

```
                        <form action="" class="feedback__form" id="feedback-form">
                            <div class="feedback__group">
                                <div class="feedback__box">
                                    <input type="text" name="user_name" class="feedback__input" id="name" required placeholder="First Name">
                                    <label for="name" class="feedback__label">First Name</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="feedback__box">
                                    <input type="email" name="user_email" class="feedback__input" id="email" required placeholder="Email Address">
                                    <label for="name" class="feedback__label">Email Address</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="feedback__box">
                                <input type="text" name="user_subject" class="feedback__input" id="subject" required placeholder="Subject">
                                <label for="subject" class="feedback__label">Subject</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="feedback__box feedback__area">
                                <textarea name="user__message" id="message" class="feedback__input" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                <label for="message" class="feedback__label">Message</label>
                            </div>

                            <p class="feedback__message" id="feedback-message"></p>
                            <button type="submit" class="feedback__button button" id="feedback-submit">
                                <i class="ri-send-plane-line"></i>Send Message
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

this is the javascript

```
const feedbackForm = document.getElementById('feedback-form'),
      feedbackMessage = document.getElementById('feedback-message'),
      feedbackSubmit = document.getElementById('feedback-message')

const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
}

    emailjs.sendForm('service_mbynjbg','template_xm8yzfd','#feedback-form','SroPTASblucuUzgXt')
    .then(() =>{
     
        feedbackMessage.textContent = 'Message sent successfully :D'

        setTimeout(() =>{
            feedbackMessage.textContent = ''
        }, 5000)
         
        feedbackForm.reset()
    }, () => {
        feedbackMessage.textContent = 'Message not sent (service error)'
    })

feedbackSubmit.addEventListener('submit', sendEmail)
```

ive tried `const sendEmail = (e) => { e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, the page refreshes back to the top. This happens because the form is actually being submitted, even though you have `e.preventDefault()` in your `sendEmail` function.

You can wrap your JavaScript code in a condition that checks whether the form was actually submitted.

```
const feedbackForm = document.getElementById('feedback-form');
const feedbackMessage = document.getElementById('feedback-message');

if (feedbackForm) {
    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Place the emailjs.sendForm() and message handling code here
    };

    feedbackForm.addEventListener('submit', sendEmail);
}
```

By checking feedbackForm exists before the event listener, you ensure that the event listener is only added when the form element is present on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to change your `<button type="submit">` to `<button type="button">`. The button event changes from `submit` to `click` and you don't then need to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Here I'm using the handler to iterate over the form entries, but you can probably substitute `form` for `#feedback-form` in your sendMail arguments.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.submit');
button.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(e) {
  const form = e.target.closest('form');
  // emailjs.sendForm(...., form, ...)
  for (const entry of new FormData(form).entries()) {
    console.log(entry);
  }
}
```

```css
label, button { display: block; }
```

```html
<form action="/doesntdoanything">
  <label for="firstname">First name</label>
  <input name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
  <input name="lastname" id="lastname" />
  <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```